# How do Hogwarts students get snacks outside the three main meals

Tags: harry-potter

They have 3 meals every day - breakfast, lunch and dinner but what if they want to eat something between the meals? Do the have to ask someone or go somewhere?

Comment: If I recall they either had stuff they bought from when they went into town, or they snuck food from the kitchen. I don't remember which books at the moment mentioned those instances. Other then that I think it would work the same way boarding school systems would work.

Comment: If they have three meals a day, they aren't going to starve if they can't get a snack.

Comment: @Des I am sure that like many Britsh Public schools there would also be a tuck shop for the boarders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Students can steal food from the kitchens (if they have the capacity).

> *‘Ah – your father happened to leave it in my possession and I thought
> you might like it.’ Dumbledore’s eyes twinkled. ‘Useful things … **your
> father used it [his invisibility cloak] mainly for sneaking off to the kitchens to steal food
> when he was here.’***
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

They can sneak out of Hogwarts entirely and go to the nearby town.

> *It felt as though they had already won the Quidditch Cup; the party went on all day and well into the night. **Fred and George Weasley disappeared for a couple of hours and returned with armfuls of bottles of Butterbeer, pumpkin fizz and several bags full of Honeydukes sweets.***
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban</sup></sub>

If the house-elves like you, they'll give you food.

> *As they prepared to take their leave, **many of the surrounding elves
> pressed in upon them, offering snacks to take back upstairs.** Hermione
> refused, with a pained look at the way the elves kept bowing and
> curtseying, but Harry and Ron loaded their pockets with cream cakes
> and pies.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

You can have it sent from home (by owl post)

> *Harry hadn’t had a single letter since Hagrid’s note, something that
> Malfoy had been quick to notice, of course. **Malfoy’s eagle owl was
> always bringing him packages of sweets from home,** which he opened
> gloatingly at the Slytherin table.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

You can purchase *speciality* foods from the Weasley brothers.

> ***‘Range of sweets to make you ill,’** George whispered, keeping a wary
> eye on Mrs Weasley’s back. ‘Not seriously ill, mind, just ill enough
> to get you out of a class when you feel like it. Fred and I have been
> developing them this summer. They’re double-ended, colour-coded chews.
> If you eat the orange half of the Puking Pastilles, you throw up.
> Moment you’ve been rushed out of the lesson for the hospital wing, you
> swallow the purple half –’*
>
> *‘“– which restores you to full fitness, enabling you to pursue the
> leisure activity of your own choice during an hour that would
> otherwise have been devoted to unprofitable boredom.” **That’s what
> we’re putting in the adverts, anyway,’** whispered Fred, who had edged
> over out of Mrs Weasley’s line of vision and was now sweeping a few
> stray Doxys from the floor and adding them to his pocket. ‘But they
> still need a bit of work. At the moment our testers are having a bit
> of trouble stopping themselves puking long enough to swallow the
> purple end.’*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sup></sub>

Comment: If the house-elves *don't* like you, they give you food anyway. "Miss will please take her food and go."

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Hehe. I think they like her well enough, they just don't want her to be there.

Answer (score 0):

In *Chamber of Secrets*, Crabbe and Goyle just walk out of the great hall with some cakes. They don't even try to hide it. Mind you, they are Slytherins, so there's no guarantee that what they're doing is in any way allowed.